# How to remove local Git repositories, remembered by Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, egit

When sharing project into EGit, Eclipse dialog proposes various repositories, which were used previously:

[image]

Are there any ways to remove entries from this list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove a repository by opening the `Git Repositories` view (`Window > Show View > Other > Git > Git Repositories`) and selecting `Remove Repository` in the right click menu.

For more details see [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Removing_Repositories)